# How to install Predis

Tags: php, apache-2.2, redis

I am trying to install Predis, but keep getting a 500 Server errror.  Here is what I have done.

1.) Have apache and php installed on Ubuntu Natty.

2.) Used the instructions on this page http://redis.io/download to download Redis.

3.) Ran the following example to confirm that Redis is working:

```
$ src/redis-cli
redis> set foo bar
OK
redis> get foo
"bar"
```

4.) Have a local website at /home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com/index.php and have confirmed that php is working.

5.) Downloaded the .zip version of Predis ( https://github.com/nrk/predis Version: v0.6.6-PHP5.2 ), and unzipped the contents to /home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com/.  So now Predis is here: /home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com/nrk-predis-3bf1230/

6.) Opened the /home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com/index.php page.  Here is its contents:

```
<?
define("PREDIS_BASE_PATH", "nrk-predis-3bf1230/lib/");
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
$file = PREDIS_BASE_PATH.strtr($class, '\\', '/').'.php';
 if (file_exists($file)) {
require $file;
 return true;
 }
 });
 $redis = new Predis_Client();
 $redis->set('foo', 'bar');
 $value = $redis->get('foo');
 ?>
```

I have tried changing:

```
$redis = new Predis_Client();
```

to:

```
$redis = new Predis\Client();
```

Have tried changing the the PREDIS_BASE_PATH to:

```
/nrk-predis-3bf1230/lib
/home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com/nrk-predis-3bf1230/lib/
/home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com/nrk-predis-3bf1230/lib
```

Have done a chmod +x on both:

```
/home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com/nrk-predis-3bf1230/
/home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com
```

And doing all of the above always results in a 500 server error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do the error logs say about the 500?

Comment: if you install xdebug, you get better error messages

Comment: Here is the error: [Wed Sep 07 13:43:40 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Predis_Client' not found in /home/user/Dropbox/documents/www/mywebsite.com/index.php on line 10

Comment: Hosting from Dropbox.. Well, that's one way to get a clustered filesystem. Definitely not the right one.

Answer (score 1):

When using Predis **v0.6.x** you just need to pick the file `lib/Predis.php` from the zip and `require()` it in your scripts. Autoloading is not needed with versions of Predis prior to **v0.7.0-dev**, which is the current development version of the library in the master branch of the git repository.